# Animating margin changes in qml

Tags: qt, qml, transition, state

I am trying to animate the margin value change with animation in **QML**, but i cant. The animation is not working

This is my state

```
State {
    name: "up"
    PropertyChanges {
        target: drag_line
        anchors.topMargin: 50
    }
```

And in the transition  i tried

```
transitions: [

    Transition {
        to: "up"
        NumberAnimation {  properties: "margin" ;easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad;duration: 300 }
    }

]
```

I also tried the number animation but it also didn't work. Is there any way, am i doing something wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property is not `margin` but `anchors.topMargin`

This is my working example:

```
ApplicationWindow {
  visible: true
  width: 500
  height: 500

  Rectangle {
    width: 100
    height: 100
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    color: "red"

    Rectangle {
      id: iRect
      color: "blue"
      width: 40
      height: 40
      anchors.top: parent.top

      states: [State {
        name: "up"
        when: iMouseArea.pressed
        PropertyChanges {
          target: iRect
          anchors.topMargin: 50
        }
      }]

      transitions: [
        Transition {
          to: "up"
          NumberAnimation { properties:"anchors.topMargin"; easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad;duration: 300 }        
        }
      ]
    }

    MouseArea{
      id: iMouseArea
      anchors.fill: parent
    }
  }
}
```